# Trigger.io Ajax Requests - with Parse Facebook User authentication

Tags: ajax, rest, trigger.io, parse-platform

I'm trying to authenticate users from Trigger.io, ideally via Facebook.

I authenticate the user via Facebook (using the Parse Facebook module), and pass their access token, acess expiry date, and facebook Id to my call to Parse.

It is here things go wrong. Whenever I try and post this data via Ajax to the Parse REST API, I get an error in my forge/Trigger console reading:

> { type: 'EXPECTED_FAILURE',   content: '{"code":107,"error":"This
>   endpoint only supports Content-Type: application/json requests, not
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded."}',   statusCode: '400',   message:
>   'HTTP error code received from server: 400' }

The code I used to try and post this data is...

```
function auth(facebookId,accessToken,expirationDate) {
    forge.logging.log('auth started');
    forge.request.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/users',
        headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': config.parseAppId,
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': config.parseRestKey,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "authData": {
                "facebook": {
                    "id" : facebookId,
                    "access_token": accessToken,
                    "expiration_date": expirationDate
                  }
            }
        },
        success: function (data) {
            forge.logging.log('auth finished 1');
            forge.logging.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
            forge.logging.log('auth finished 2');
            forge.logging.log(error);
        }
    })//success
} //auth
```

I can't figure out how to send this as a JSON object/ in the correct format. If anyone has any ideas they'd be much appreciated. Thanks. Josh.

Comment: Could you try using setting the contentType attribute in the options object you pass to forge.request.ajax. Rather than setting 'Content-Type' directly in the headers?

Comment: Cool - thanks Amir - that did help.

Although I now get the following:

{ type: 'EXPECTED_FAILURE',
[INFO]   content: '{"code":107,"error":"invalid json: authData%5Bfacebook%5D%5Bid%5D=199714297&authData%5Bfacebook%5D%5Baccess_token%5D=BAAE5X1h2zPQBAALpl90JLv5hu8phZA0LwQi8xeNAPdZA9HVNL1kNeNceWuuXYTZBHoAx3AVmgTpRFwu9uFRsUK7ER4bwZCmw0EeZBlTLbrVUneyKp8CRASp3Gux2h5ZCSceUD5rUikmAZDZD&authData%5Bfacebook%5D%5Bexpiration_date%5D=2013-01-18T23%3A45%3A33.601Z"}',
[INFO]   statusCode: '400',
[INFO]   message: 'HTTP error code received from server: 400' }

Not 100% sure why, but I'll keep playing.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever the `data` option passed to `forge.requests.ajax` is an object like in your example, what actually gets posted is a query string that represents the object. The `contentType` option merely allows you to set the `Content-Type` header, it does not effect how objects are encoded for the request.

However if the `data` option is just a string, then this string is used as the body of the request. You can generate a JSON string to use as the body using `JSON.parse` like so:

```
forge.request.ajax({
    ...
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "authData": {
            "facebook": {
                "id" : facebookId,
                "access_token": accessToken,
                "expiration_date": expirationDate
              }
        }
    })
});
```